# Python module not found but exists in folder

Tags: python

I'm trying to execute a simple PY file and I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker_pull.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Looking at Python install folder I found requests module under:  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.7.1\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests`. How can I force Python to use the module already installed ?

P.S: I don't have internet connection in this machine.

Comment: Add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.7.1\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor` to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, or add it directly to `sys.path` in the code.

Comment: Thanks, it solve my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very typical issue, so I will leave this here for future reference.

If I have a project called: my_project

```
.
└── my_project
    ├── first_folder
    ├── second_folder
    └── third_folder
```

What you want to do is one of these two things:

1. PYTHONPATH (only Python)

`cd ~/my_project && export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)`

change dir to root dir, and export that dir to PYTHONPATH, so when Python runs it looks in the PYTHONPATH.

2. PATH (everything)

`cd ~/my_project && export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)`

Same as above!

This needed to live somewhere since it took me a while to figure out. So for anyone in the future who needs help with this!

Answer (score -1):

Check the python version you are calling. Run "python --version". If it's not 3.7.1, that's the problem. If it returns a version beginning with "2", then try running the python3 binary instead.