# VSCode: How to import a module from my code path to another file in the same path?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug my python app using VSCode. But I cannot configure my environment right. Attempting to import a class from one folder in my source path to another, gives me this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mb/Library/source/sandbox/lib/lib.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app.main import MyClass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

I created a simple app to exhibit the problem. My source path looks like this:

```
sandbox
+-- .vscode
    --- launch.json
+-- app
    --- __init__.py
    --- main.py
+-- lib
    -- lib.py
```

```py
# main.py

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Creating object...')
    def print_message(self, message):
        print(message)
```

```py
# lib.py

from app.main import MyClass


myclass = MyClass()
myclass.print_message('hello, world!')
```

Trying to run `lib.py` using the default configuration to run current file I get the error message above.

Additionally, I created a `.vscode/launch.json` to set the working directory, but to no avail. Here is my `launch.json`:

```js
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "main"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm sure, I'm missing a simple setup, but I can't put my finger on it.

---

**Note**

- The interpreter used is: Python 3.7.5 64-bit
- The above code works fine in PyCharm.
- After some reading on VSCode documentation, I added `"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"}` to `launch.json`, but that didn't do any good.
- I also created a VSCode *task* to echo the `${workspaceFolder}` variable, and the output was stripped of all the `\` from the path, as if they were not escaped.
  Here is the task in `.vscode/tasks.json`:

```js
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "workspaceFolder",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "echo ${workspaceFolder}"
      }
    ]
  }
```

And here is the output that got from it:

```sh
> Executing task: echo C:\Users\mb\Library\source\sandbox <

C:UsersmbLibrarysourcesandbox

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Comment: Can you check the status bar of the vscode to specify the interpreter to be used.

Comment: Sure. It is: Python 3.7.5 64-bit

Comment: Yes just click on that to check the environment used to run your python program

Comment: Ok, the path I read is: `/usr/local/bin/python3`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes the path you should be able to choose your environment for the python project. make sure it is the same

Comment: For more info refer this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: What folder do you have open for your project? And which debug configuration are you using?

Comment: `sandbox` is the folder open in VSCode. And my configuration is mentioned above. If you are still missing some information, please clarify what's missing.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58084390/11317776)

basically, what you wanna do is `cd /path/to/sandbox` then `export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)`

Now that you have the root dir of your app in the python-path.

You simply treat everything at this level.

`from app.main import MyClass` <- correct and should work!

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to help you out.When you want to import a file which is not in the current directory, do like this.

```
from . import main
```

For second problem visit this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623138/vscode-how-to-set-working-directory-for-debug)